# Extract value from list add to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists such as `pa_l = [[ABU, XXXXX, 0],[AZE, CCCCC,0]]`. This `pa_l` contains 243 lists. `iso_pa` is a list with only country codes, such as:

> ABU and AZE (plus others)

I need to create a dictionary `all_countries = {}` where each country code has its name. For this I have created the following code:

```
for i in iso_pa:
    if i not in all_countries.keys():
        all_countries[i] = pa_l[i][1]
```

But this is not working. I would be pleased if someone could help me.

Comment: are you trying to set entire list as key? dictionary key can only be of type string and integer...

Comment: and don't be lazy with variable names, use descriptive names, if you keep using a, b, c, d, i for everything, you will loose track of what are you doing very quickly and overcomplicate your code.

Comment: So... you're describing the desired result by showing code that doesn't do it right? Makes sense.

Comment: and read your error outputs, it probably says the same thing I said in my first comment

Comment: I was not trying to set the entire list. I was trying to extract solely the second item (1 in python), which is the country. I put here "easy variables" but I even have a description in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range (len (iso_pa)):
  if iso_pa [i] not in all_countries.keys():
    all_countries [iso_pa [i]] = pa_l [i][1]
```

Comment: This work perfectly fine, it pairs the country code with the country!

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated, you want to prepare a dictionary where country_code maps to a country name. There is a small fix for that in our code:

```
for i in iso_pa:
    if i not in all_countries:
        all_countries[i[0]] = i[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of lists is not really a good structure for looking up the codes that you have in the `iso_pa` list. So turn that longer list into a dictionary first, and then pick from that the names that you need in the result:

```
dict_pa_l = dict([lst[0:2] for lst in pa_l])
all_countries = [{code: dict_pa_l[code]} for code in iso_pa]
```

Comment: This creates a list with dictionaries on it. The answer below creates a dictionary with all the values. Both are useful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` format `pa_l` such that it will be simpler to access the first occurrence of the country and its code:

```
import itertools
pa_l = [['ABU', 'XXXXX', 0],['AZE', 'CCCCC',0]]
new_data = {a:list(b)[0][-1] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(pa_l, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
```

Output:

```
{'ABU': 0, 'AZE': 0}
```